# Understanding how this derivative was taken

Tags: derivatives

> I am pouring water into a conical cup 8cm tall and 6cm across the top.
>   If the volume of the cup at time t is $V(t)$, how fast is the water
>   level ($h$) rising in terms of $V'(t)$?

The solution in the book is:

> Take the water volume, given by
>
> $$\frac{1}{3}\pi(\frac{3}{8})^2h^3$$
>
> Then differentiate with respect to $t$:
>
> $$V' = h'\pi(\frac{3}{8})^2h^2$$
>
> Which gives
>
> $$h' = \frac{64V'}{9{\pi}h^2}$$

I did not understand how this differentiation happened, when *there was no $t$ in the formula to differentiate*! If you differentiate with respect to $h$, though, you get something similar:

$$\dfrac{9{\pi}h^2}{64}$$

But I'm not sure how $V'$ fits into this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $V'=\frac{dV}{dt}$ and $h'=\frac{dh}{dt}$ The chain rule has been used.

Comment: @GoodDeeds So...? I honestly don't understand.

Comment: @GoodDeeds So both are a function of $t$. Where is the chain rule used here?

Comment: $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dh}\frac{dh}{dt}$ has been used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer in words, making GoodDeeds point more clear.
Notice how if you differentiate the whole term with respect to t

$$
V = \frac{1}{3}{\pi}(\frac{3}{8})^2h^3
$$

use chain rule on the h such that the expression becomes

$$
h'*constants *3h^2
$$

where h' is the derivative of h with.

All thats left is to deal with the constants and rearrange.

Comment: sorry, i'm not used to using this formatting

Comment: FTFY, use `$\frac$` for fractions

Comment: Cheers. But now do you see where the chain rule is used to get to the solution?

Comment: Sort of... I though the chain rule could only be used when you have a composite function, like $$h(x) = v(u(x))$$ Then $$h'(x) = u'(x)v'(u(x))$$ But I don't see how that would apply here.

Comment: Yes, you're right, compare the problem to what you've just written. The whole term of V is differentiated wrt h then multiplied by the derivative of h wrt to t... i.e chain rule.

Comment: So... $$V'(t) = h'(t)V'(h(t))$$ Oh, well duh! I was looking at $h$ like a variable, when in fact you have a composite function!

Comment: So to differentiate _with respect to_ a variable doesn't necessarily mean that the variable needs to literally exist in the function... it just means that there has to be a function of that variable somewhere in the function.

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Intuitively, we know that the water level h changes with time so its a natural assumption to make that h=h(t).